# Unable to use Retrofit with Coroutines with KotlinExtensions

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

So here's the deal . This is the ApiInterface:

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("api/fetch-some-info")
    suspend fun fetchSomeInfo(
        @Query("some_query_param") queryParam: String,
    ): Call<Data>
}
```

Here is how I generate it

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(mOkHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().build()))
                .baseUrl(url)
                .build().create(AdMediationV2.class);
```

here is Data class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Data(
    @Json(name = "data")
    val info: String)
```

Now I am trying to call the function and receive data using KotlinExtensions for Retrofit, I am using `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'`

This is how I am trying to call this function. I want to keep a reference of the job so I might be able to cancel it later.

```
val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async{
                api.fetchSomeInfo("Param").await().let { data->
                                                          //handle response}
```

But I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for retrofit2.Call<Data>
```

According to documentation I dont even need to add Call to interface, but unless I do I cannot call .await(). It is marked as red and this is what it says

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public suspend fun <T : Any> Call<TypeVariable(T)>.await(): TypeVariable(T) defined in retrofit2
public suspend fun <T : Any> Call<TypeVariable(T)?>.await(): TypeVariable(T)? defined in retrofit2
```

What am I doing wrong?

> Note: The Api functions properly, when used in java code, call.enqueue() it works fine.
> It also works just fine in this code :

```
var call : Deferred<Data>? = null
MainScope().launch {
        call = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
             api.fetchSomeInfo("Param")
        }

        call?.await().let {//handle reponse}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function in your interface should return `Data` instead of `Call<Data>` since it's a suspend function. And since it's a suspend function, there will be no need for calling `await()` on anything. You can just call `fetchSomeInfo()` directly in a coroutine, without any concern about what dispatcher it is called from either.

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("api/fetch-some-info")
    suspend fun fetchSomeInfo(
        @Query("some_query_param") queryParam: String,
    ): Data
}

//...

val job = someCoroutineScope.launch {
    try {
        val data = api.fetchSomeInfo("Param") 
        // handle data 
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        // handle errors
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `suspend` keyword from your function so it does have to return a `Call<Data>` that you will then have to call `await()` on, but that's just adding convolution, so don't do that.

A couple notes about your coroutine... it is a code smell to create a coroutine scope just to launch a single coroutine and then immediately lose the reference. You should be launching from a persistent CoroutineScope that you presumably will be cancelling when you want it to go out of scope.

And when you call a Retrofit API (either by using a suspend function or calling `await()` on a Call object), you must wrap it in try/catch to handle any of the many possible errors that might occur.

Comment: There are a few cases where I need to cancel the network operation. As per my understanding if I call job.cancel() it will not cancel that operation. So I am trying to use this code https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt

Comment: I googled what code smell meant.. Yes it seems to be so, I think its better not to go with coroutines in this particular context of my code

Comment: Calling await on a call has the same effect as calling a suspend function version of the function as in my code above. And to the best of my knowledge, calling cancel on the Job will also cancel the request under the hood. The code smell is not coroutines, it’s how you’re using CoroutineScope. I would say it would also be a code smell to use Calls at all in a new project unless you don’t want to use coroutines whatsoever. The point of await() is for dealing with legacy code that hasn’t been updated to use coroutines yet.